# Moving the value of a cell to the next one if condition is met

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have the existing code that works great to an extent. All I am trying to add in the process is every time that there's a NaN value for a given month, copy the value of the most recent previous month but only for the same year.

If for a given year there's only 1 value then all 12 months should have that same value and if all 12 are NaN, they should remain NaN.

Existing code:

```
data_list = []

for f in excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, header = None)

    new_col_coords = [[6,1], [7,1], [3,1], [1,0], [0,0]]
    new_columns = [x for x in [df.iloc[i, j] for i, j in new_col_coords]]
    header_row = 11
    df = df.T.set_index(header_row).T
    df = df.reset_index(drop = True).iloc[header_row:].reset_index(drop = True)
    df.columns.names = [None]
    df[['Region-INF', 'Series Name', 'Series ID']] = new_columns
    df = df[['Region-INF', 'Series Name', 'Series ID', 'View Description', 'Index Type', 'Year',
             'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']]
```

Input sample data

```
Region-INF  Series Name  Series ID     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May   Jun
Pacific     All Items    CUUR0490SDD   2.9  2.8  NaN  NaN  2.52  2.04
Pacific     All Items    CUE07890SDF   NaN  2.64 NaN  2.44 2.59  3
Pacific     All Items    CUE073310SAF  2.1  2.4  NaN  2.21 3.45  NaN
```

Expected output:

```
Region-INF  Series Name  Series ID     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May   Jun
Pacific     All Items    CUUR0490SDD   2.9  2.8  2.8  2.8  2.52  2.04
Pacific     All Items    CUE07890SDF   3    2.64 2.64 2.44 2.59  3
Pacific     All Items    CUE073310SAF  2.1  2.4  2.4  2.21 3.45  3.45
```

Comment: `df.ffill(axis=1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang that doesn't work as expected. I want the values to carry over only between months and ONLY from any previous month to the next one.

Comment: Works fine with your data. You may want to extract the month columns only, e.g.: `df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].ffill(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your' question right:

```py
df.loc[df['Jan'].isna(), 'Jan'] = df[df['Jan'].isna()].apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()][-1], axis=1)
df.loc[:, 'Jan':] = df.loc[:, 'Jan':].ffill(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Region-INF Series Name     Series ID  Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun
0    Pacific   All Items   CUUR0490SDD  2.9  2.80  2.80  2.80  2.52  2.04
1    Pacific   All Items   CUE07890SDF  3.0  2.64  2.64  2.44  2.59  3.00
2    Pacific   All Items  CUE073310SAF  2.1  2.40  2.40  2.21  3.45  3.45
```

Comment: You did yes. That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Comment: how would you go about moving the last value of given year/month i.e Jun: 2.04 to Jan of next year since it's NaN?